# How can I classify a NoneType?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From my understanding, NoneType means the returns object will be nothing. However, why is the code

`print ("Hello")`

be a NoneType? It prints the str 'Hello'.

Say it is a NoneType type because the word ("Hello") is not saved in the memory. Then why is the code

`input("What is your name?")`

be a str ?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: The purpose of `print` is to print some text, not to _return_ anything. It doesn't need to return anything. Whereas the whole purpose of `input` is to get a string from the user, and you get it via its return value.

Comment: `NoneType` is the class (i.e. type) for the language-guaranteed singleton `None`, i.e. `type(None)`. So, what you are seeing here is that `print` returns `None`, which it does.  `input`, on the other hand, returns a `str` always.